# Convert service "display name" to "key name" C#

Tags: c#

Basically, I have a large list of the "display names" services have in the service manager (ie "Background Intelligent Transfer Service") and I'm trying to figure out how to "convert" them to the service "key names" (ie "BITS"). Looking it up, I saw there was [one solution](http://www.chami.com/tips/delphi/040598D.html) written in another language (delphi) that didn't appear to use any kind of dictionary, which implies to me that there should be some way to do it in C#. Maybe I'm just googling wrong, but I found surprisingly few relevant hits for this. Has anyone figured out how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will print out the Display Name followed by its Service Name (referred to as key name in your question):

```
var services = ServiceController.GetServices();
foreach(var service in services)
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", service.DisplayName, service.ServiceName);
}
```

Reference System.ServiceProcess to get access to the ServiceController.

EDIT: To convert to a dictionary (for ease of look ups) use

```
var serviceNameLookups = ServiceController.GetServices().ToDictionary(s => s.DisplayName, s => s.ServiceName);
```

then retrieve via:

```
string serviceName;
serviceNameLookups.TryGetValue("Background Intelligent Transfer Service", out serviceName)
```

Comment: Ah, knew something like this would be floating around here somewhere! Hopefully the Google results will be a bit more robust with this answer.

Comment: @KnightOfNi Feel free to mark it as the answer if it helped you. If you haven't marked it as the answer due to not creating a dictionary I'll edit it in one second...

Comment: Sorry, I should have marked as accepted. I had been iterating through to create the Dictionary "manually", but I assume your method is a bit faster, so I'm glad I waited :)